# Why does $10^{\log_{10}2} = 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Why does $10^{\log_{10}2} = 2$ ?

I tried to draw a graph but that didn't help

Comment: The definition of $\log$ is as follows: $\log_a b=c\iff a^c=b$. If $c=\log_{10} 2$, then $10^c=2$, Q.E.D.

Comment: How did you draw a graph.

Comment: Because $\,f(f^{-1}(x)) = x\,$ by definition. What's your definition of $\,\log_{10}(\,\cdot\,)\,$?

Comment: @KingTut Tut use a computer program.

Comment: The value of $\log_{10}2$ is, by definition, the number $x$ such that $10^x=2$. So what happens when you plug it in for $x$? It makes the equation true.

Comment: @Student nice! i am used to plotting graphs between variables.

Comment: @anon I got it, thank you. I feel so dumb

Comment: If $$\log_a c = b$$ then this means that $$a^b = c.$$ The latter is just simply another way of writing the former logarithm. Therefore, if we consider the case where $a = 10$ and $c = 2$ then we have$$\log_{10} 2 = b$$ which means that $$10^b = 2$$ and thus we arrive at the conclusion that $$10^{\log_{10}2} = 2.$$ *And*, because $10 = a$ and $2 = c$, then we arrive at a more general conclusion: $$a^{\log_a c} = c.$$ We can now put, like how we would similarly put in division, that *the base $a$ and $\log_{a}$ cancel out to yeild c*.

Therefore, what does this imply in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of log base $b$ of $x$, or $log_{b}(x)$, is the solution $y$ such that $b^y = x$. Therefore, this is true given the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If $$\log_a c = b$$ then this means that $$a^b = c.$$ The latter is just simply another way of writing the former logarithm. Therefore, if we consider the case where $a = 10$ and $c = 2$ then we have$$\log_{10} 2 = b$$ which means that $$10^b = 2$$ and thus we arrive at the conclusion that $$10^{\log_{10}2} = 2.$$ *And*, because $10 = a$ and $2 = c$, then we arrive at a more general conclusion: $$a^{\log_a c} = c.$$ We can now put, like how we would similarly put in division, that *the base $a$ and $\log_{a}$ cancel out to yeild c*.

Therefore in your case, *the base $10$ and $\log_{10}$ cancel out to yeild $2$*.

Answer (score 0):

$\log_a x=log_a x$

Due to definition:

⇒ $x=a^{log_a x}$

$log _{10}2=log_{10}2$  ⇒ $ 2=10^{log_{10}2}$